# Triggers behavior with actions

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

please look at this xaml code:

```
       <Style x:Key="WowButton" TargetType="Button" >
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                  
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                         From="300" To="500 ">                                
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>                        
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation  Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                          From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="1x">                                
                        </DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I used this style on a button in the Main Window.
How is that that when I leave the button it rotates and it's width is getting smaller, but after I click on it - it's width doesn't change back?

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970493.aspx):

> In some cases, it might appear that you can't change the value of a
>   property after it has been animated.

You can solve this by adding new `Storyboards` to change `Width` property:

```
<Style x:Key="WowButton" TargetType="Button" >
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">                 
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="30"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                                     From="300" To="500 ">                                
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>                        
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="150" To="300"/>
                 </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation  Duration="0:0:2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                      From="0" To="360" RepeatBehavior="1x">                                
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="300" To="150 "/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `Trigger`'s basic setter's, `Storyboard`'s do not get an auto `RemoveStoryboard` call to remove them.

Thus it's upto you to get rid of them when they do not apply anymore. If you were using a `Trigger` then you can use `Trigger.EnterActions` and `Trigger.ExitActions` to do the apply and remove of `Storyboard`'s. This does not exist for `EventTrigger`'s.

In your case Just remove the click `Storyboard` on the `MouseLeave` event and vice-versa.

something like: (note we have added a `x:Name` for the `BeginStoryboard`'s)

```
<Style x:Key="WowButton"
        TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
              Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="300" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize"
              Value="30" />
      <Setter Property="FontWeight"
              Value="Bold" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
              Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Yellow" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="150" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize"
              Value="25" />
    </Trigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
      <BeginStoryboard x:Name="clickStoryboard">
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25"
                            From="300"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                            To="500 " />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
      <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="leaveStoryboard" />
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
      <BeginStoryboard x:Name="leaveStoryboard">
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                            From="0"
                            RepeatBehavior="1x"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                            To="360" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
      <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="clickStoryboard" />
    </EventTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You **don't have** to create new `Storyboard`'s to remove old one's. Just use `RemoveStoryboard`'s appropriately to get rid of em.